# How to install Cffi python module on Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: windows, python-cffi, cffi

Is there a way to start working with cffi in the Windows 7 64-bit environment without using the MinGW ? What all packages need to be installed for the same?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the links in http://cffi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html, sections about Windows 32 and 64.  In two words, assuming you are using CPython (and not PyPy), the requirements are the same as when using (the same version of) CPython to develop C extension modules.  These requirements are documented at various places, which e.g. you should find by following the links mentioned above.